# how to Implement custom share functionality in SharePoint 2013 To share an article via email programmatically?

Tags: development, ootb, share

Client Says That users will have the ability to share an article via email. This will take the form of an icon on the page that will have the same effect as the “share link” OOTB functionality.

Is It Possible?

Comment: The OOTB 'Share' functionality is not purely for sharing the article link through email. It actually assigns permissions to the users and then sends a mail to the list of users. If you are looking for a custom link just for sharing the article through an email, check if an anchor tag with mailto:subject=<<Your Mail Subject>>&body=<<Article link/URL>> will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I tried to search on the blogs but I didn’t find anything related to programmatic-ally ,Then I find the function `"DisplaySharingDialog (webUrl, listId, listItemId)"` that is used to open the dialog box for sharing users.

```
    function SharePage()
    {
        EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharingDialog', 
            function () {
            DisplaySharingDialog(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, _spPageContextInfo.pageListId, _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId.toString());
                    }
                    );
    }
```

Since this function is defined in Sharing.js file that why we are trying to ensure that Sharing.js is already loaded before calling DisplaySharingDialog function.

Comment: Can we use this method for sharing each list item?